# 2012 Mac Mini with Fusion Drive only Boots while Verbose Mode

Tags: startup, mac-mini, fusion-drive

I have a mac mini 2012 which only boots to completion when in verbose mode. when just normal booted it gives the fan symbol for a few seconds and then loops back around.

I've done a time machine reinstall and also replaced the HDD of the fusion drive and rebuilt it.

So I'm at a loss now as to why this is happening.

Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: I don't know why this happens, but it is an interesting case of a [**Heisenbug**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug). If it happened to me, I would probably set the machine to always boot verbosely and forget about it. I used to have my macs boot verbosely anyway. I think you can set it up with `sudo nvram boot-args -v`. But apparently, these days you have to be booted into recovery mode for that to work (unless you have a pretty old OS).

Comment: Interesting I'm on 10.12 ...not too old not to new either....maybe I'll try the verbose mode thing

Comment: The fan is controlled by the SMC. You can reset the SMC by while holding command-shift-option pressing the power button.  However, I’ve never heard of the fan symbol... I search the net briefly and didn’t see anything either. Are you sure it’s a fan and not the FireWire symbol?

Comment: The fan swirly.....like when you shut down your iPhone... the 12 bars in a circular pattern which rotate/pulse

Comment: 10.12 is new enough to have SIP, and that is (I think) what stops you from doing the `nvram` command when booted normally

Comment: The closest I get to a “fan” symbol [on this page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204156) is the Firewire symbol. Which might indicate a stuck T key, but that does not explain how you can boot normally in verbose mode. I'm still puzzled.

Comment: Does it boot in safe mode? Hold the shift key all the way from the chimes to the login screen.

Comment: @Tetsujin no it doesn't.....just in verbose.